# Is 'abroad' the right word to use here?

Tags: word-choice

> We are doing research in Asia and abroad.

I want to express the meaning that we are doing research mainly in Asia, as well as in other non-Asian areas, which are not the main focus. Is 'abroad' the right word to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. [*Abroad* means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abroad) *in or to a foreign country/countries.* It is quite common to use 'X' country ***and abroad*** in various contexts. Have a look -

> [Aviation news from India and abroad](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/specials/flight-plan/aviation-news-from-india-and-abroad/article24865790.ece).

Comment: It's appropriate if the writer is in Asia. If they are not, it's _in Asia and elsewhere_.